# Protractor/jasmine tests timeout on Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, cmd, jasmine, protractor

My team and I have a suite of 122 protractor tests. The jasmine tests are straight forward

1. log on
2. navigate to page
3. fill out form
4. assert results

The tests are written using protractor 5.4, jasmine 3.3, and type script 3.1, and executed using nodeJs 10.5.3, npm 6.9.0.
Our tests target a remote development server.

running the following commands on both my local and remote machines the tests pass.

- open cmd
- `git clone ...`
- `cd repo-name`
- `npm install`
- `npm run e2e:dev`

tests are run using a headless chromium browser. here is the e2e config

```
exports.config = {
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        'headless',
        'disable-gpu',
        'window-size=1024,1536',
        'disable-browser-side-navigation',
        'disable-web-security'
      ],
      useAutomationExtension: false,
      prefs: {
        'download': {
          'prompt_for_download': false,
          'directory_upgrade': true,
          'default_directory': path.resolve("./target/downloads")
          }
        }
      }      
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: '[internal server url]',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true
  },
  onPrepare() {
    rmDir(path.resolve("./target/downloads"));
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    var environment = jasmine.getEnv();
    environment.addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    environment.addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        savePath: 'target/junitreporter',
        consolidateAll: true,
        captureStdout: true
      })
    );
  }
};
```

Jenkins is running as a windows service using a domain account that has local admin privileges. Before March 12 the job was successfully running every week night at 10 pm. starting March 12th the job fails because 30-40 tests throw jasmine timeouts. 
`31m Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`
We tried increasing the default timeout, but that did not resolve the issue.

We are running Jenkins 2.169 on Java 1.8. I have ruled out RAM, AV, and project configuration files. It really seems like Jenkins 2.169 windows batch commands are the culprit and I am not sure how to resolve this.

We also tried running the commands using git bash's shell from Jenkins and we get the same results.

Has anyone else run into a similar issue, and were you able to resolve it?

Comment: is the failed test are passing when you run it locally?. And, Are the same test are failing daily?

Comment: yes failed tests pass locally and when I log onto the remote server and run the tests using the same account the runs Jenkins.

Comment: A majority of the same tests are consistently failing. there are less than 10 intermittent failures. It appears the more steps in the test the more likely it is to fail.

Comment: Since it was consistently passing few days and now the scripts are failing with inconsistency, The failure may be with the recent update wrt to jenkins ,node libraries and chrome version in the remote machine. Can you confirm whether the versions are same few days back and none of them were updated?

Comment: We stay up to date with jenkins and plug-ins. I know there has been at least 1 jenkins update and a dozen or so plug-in updates. In the 3 years it's been running, this is the first time an updated broke a build.